# Using Custom Controller to extend module controller in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

It appears that in Zend Framework 2, every controller seems to extend the AbstractActionController by default.

I was thinking if there's a way for all my controllers to extend a CustomController that in turn extends the AbstractActionController.

The purpose of this CustomController, is to do checks like whether a user is authorized to access my other controllers or not and also may be generate menu navigation.

Is this still a good idea and if so, will doing this work?

```
**IndexController.php**

class IndexController extends CustomController {

}

**CustomController.php** 

class CustomController extends AbstractActionController {

}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can extend a base class and it will work.

Is it a good idea ? It really depends on your project.
For authentication and permission check, you could also use a module like [ZfcRbac](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac) or [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize)

For navigation, there is [spiffy-navigation](https://github.com/spiffyjr/spiffy-navigation)

If you use php 5.4+, Traits can also be an alternative to inheritance